# Magento 2.3.0 - The store that was requested wasn't found

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3, store-switcher

I have a multi website | Store | Store View setup on one magento 2.3.0 install, setup using this [**guide.**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html)

For example

- xyz.com
- xyz.com/us
- xyz.com/uk

As of late the main site **xyz.com** gives the following error, this only happens on the home page, other pages on the main site works fine, example **xyz.com/testproduct** or **xyz.com/testcategory**

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was
> requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:75
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(168):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('') #1
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('') #2
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #3
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
> Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #4
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
> NULL) #5
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores',
> NULL) #6
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callParent('getValue',
> Array) #7
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/app/code/WeltPixel/Quickview/Plugin/ScopeConfig.php(38):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}('dev/debug/debug...',
> 'store', NULL) #8
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Quickview\Plugin\ScopeConfig->aroundGetValue(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), 'dev/debug/debug...', 'store') #9
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}('dev/debug/debug...',
> 'store') #10
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue',
> Array, NULL) #11
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->getValue('dev/debug/debug...',
> 'store') #12
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #13
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
> Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #14
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
> Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...', Array) #15
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
> Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...',
> Array) #16
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
> Monolog\Logger->error('The store that ...') #17
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 18 {main}

What is causing this? and how do I fix it? any help is appreciated.

Note- I changed the main url xyz.com and xyz.com/us are the same and share the same website code  **US** if this makes any difference.

**UPDATE:**

Disabled Welpixel.
Also tried the solution in this [article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225063/magento-2-requested-store-is-not-found-when-store-switching), that didn't fix it either (reverted changes).

Get the following error now

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was
> requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:75
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(168):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('') #1
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('') #2
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #3
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
> Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #4
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
> NULL) #5
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>
> ## 6 /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #7
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
> Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #8
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
> Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...', Array) #9
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
> Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'The store that ...',
> Array) #10
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
> Monolog\Logger->error('The store that ...') #11
> /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 12 {main}

Comment: WeltPixel\Quickview\Plugin\ScopeConfig - start here

Comment: I disabled weltpixel, doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: maybe you can find some hints from this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156176/magento-2-requested-store-is-not-found

Comment: I tried the solutions, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error was being caused because of an extension conflict, disabling it, resolved the issue, the extension in question is Mageplaza Seo url (Mageplaza_SeoUrl) in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the case for OP, I had the issue as well due when trying to set up multiple stores on separate domains. Hope it helps someone.

Turns out that in nginx configuration the passed variable `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` together with `$MAGE_RUN_TYPE store` should be the store view `code`, not the store `code`.

See example below:
[image]